# Replace words in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array as follows:

```
var arr = ["apple", "banana", "carrot"];
```

I want to replace all sentences which have the words similar to the array

```
function replaceString(fruits){
return fruits.replace(arr, "---");
}
```

So if I pass a string - "An apple a day keeps", it should return "An --- a day keeps"

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression in this case, e.g.

```
"I like apples but I prefer carrots.".replace(/apple|banana|carrot/g, "---");
// I like ---s but I prefer ---s.
```

**Edit**: This might fit you better:

```
"Apple and bananasauce are my favourites, but I hate carrot and other variations of carrot."
.replace(/(\b)(apple|banana|carrot)(\b)/gi, "$1---$3");
```

If you really want an array, try this:

```
var regexp = new RegExp("(\\b)("+arr.join("|")+")[s]?(\\b)", "gi");
"Apple and bananasauce are my favourites, but I hate carrots and other variations of carrot."
.replace(regexp, "$1---$3");
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/FaZSD/.

Comment: I would add some common delimiters before and after to match exactly these words. `/apple/`, for instance, can be also found in _applesauce_, _applet_, etc.

Comment: Besides, that expression does not replace capital letters

Comment: how can I use your solution in the format I want - function replaceString(fruits){
return fruits.replace(arr, "---");
}

Comment: Think the last edition does not catch plurals... Really tricky this regexp :) Mine does not catch all cases either

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `replace` method with a regular expression, adding non-word characters to match exactly those words:

```
fruits.replace(/(\W?)(apple|banana|carrot)(s?)(\s|\W|$)/ig, "$1---$3$4");
```

Comment: Still wondering about this - `"I like apples but not applesauce, so I prefer apple.".replace(/\W?([Aa]pple|[Bb]anana|[Cc]arrot)\W?/g, '---');` replaces `apple` in `applesauce` too. Also, please put the corresponding dot etc. in the replace part, now all spaces etc. are lost.

Comment: the /i flag allow case insensitive matching

Comment: Please use `$3` as the dots/spaces are the first `()` and the third `()` group.